# HTML <select> selected option background-color CSS style

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a style for a select option's "selected" color? For example:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<FORM NAME="form1">
<SELECT NAME="mySelect" SIZE="7" style="background-color:red;">
<OPTION>Test 1
<OPTION>Test 2
<OPTION>Test 3
<OPTION>Test 4
<OPTION>Test 5
<OPTION>Test 6
<OPTION>Test 7
</SELECT>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

When I select an option it turns blue, I want to override this and
make it a different color. In the style I expected something like
"selected-color", but it doesn't exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Select List Option background colour on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover)

Comment: @doppelgreener - That "duplicate" was asked more than two years later than this

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may not be able to do this using pure CSS. But, a little javascript can do it nicely.

A crude way to do it -

```
var sel = document.getElementById('select_id');
sel.addEventListener('click', function(el){
    var options = this.children;
    for(var i=0; i < this.childElementCount; i++){
        options[i].style.color = 'white';
    }
    var selected = this.children[this.selectedIndex];
        selected.style.color = 'red';
    }, false);
```

Comment: @J.Hendrix: what i have posted works. But it will be better to use JS libraries, so that it runs in all browsers. currently works fine in Chrome & Firefox on linux.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go to some jQuery and get it done. Could post. 

luv

Comment: @arieltools: ya. will be easy with jquery.

Comment: One note, I had to place this snippet inside of `$(document).ready()` in order for my control to have rendered and the element ID be present, so `sel` was not `null`.

Comment: I want to do same thing.. I am changing color on hover and on slected...
http://jsfiddle.net/7m2sY/34/

But its not working..

Answer (score 14):

```
<select name=protect_email size=1 style="background: #009966; color: #FFF;" onChange="this.style.backgroundColor=this.options[this.selectedIndex].style.backgroundColor">    
<option value=0 style="background: #009966; color: #FFF;" selected>Protect my email</option>;  
<option value=1 style="background: #FF0000; color: #FFF;">Show email on advert</option>;
</select>;
```

http://pro.org.uk/classified/Directory?act=book&category=120

Tested it in FF,Opera,Konqueror  worked fine...

Answer (score 6):

I think the solution you may been looking for is:

```
option:checked {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px #FFFF00 inset; }
```

Comment: @Muhammed It does. But actually you need to check the browser version. Take a look at: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_checked.asp

Answer (score 5):

You cannot rely on CSS for form elements. The results vary wildly across all the browsers. I don't think Safari lets you customize *any* form elements at all.

Your best bet is to use a plugin like [jqTransform](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqtransform) (uses jQuery).

EDIT: that page doesn't seem to be working at the moment. There is also [Custom Form Elements](http://customformelements.net/) which supports MooTools and may support jQuery in the future.

Comment: Yeah, would have to to that if there's no go with jQuery. Cheers.

Comment: @ari: there are quite a few of these plugins around - I just saw two new ones today: http://swizec.com/code/styledButton/ and http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/

Comment: All these links to libraries are broken

Answer (score 2):

Currently CSS does not support this feature.

You can build your own or use a plug-in that emulates this behaviour using DIVs/CSS.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax will work in XHTML and does not work in IE6, but this is a non-javascript way:

```
option[selected] { background: #f00; }
```

If you want to do this on-the-fly, then you would have to go with javascript, the way others have suggested....

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old post, but in case it helps, you can apply this CSS to have IE11 draw a dotted outline for the focus indication of a `<select>` element so that it resembles Firefox's focus indication:
`select:focus::-ms-value {
  background: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  outline-style: dotted;
  outline-width: thin;
}`

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you can style it using option[selected] as selector, but that doesn't work in many browsers.  Also, that only allows you to style the selected option, not the option that has hover focus.

Tested to work in Chrome 9 and Firefox 3.6, doesn't work in Internet Explorer 8.

Answer (score -2):

In CSS:

SELECT OPTION:checked { background-color: red; }

Comment: Checked pseudo pselector on o select tag?

Comment: Try this code, when you expand the select object, the selected value appears in red color:

<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   SELECT OPTION:checked { background-color: red; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <select>
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1">First value</option>
   <option value="2">Second value</option>
   <option value="3">Third value</option>
   <option value="4">Forth value</option>
  </select>
 </body>
</html>

Answer (score -3):

We Can override the blue color in to our custom color 
It works for Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome:

By using this below following CSS:

```
option: checked, option: hover {
    Color: #ffffff;
    background: #614767 repeat url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlh8ACgAPAAAGFGZQAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAADwAKAAAAL+hI+py+0Po5y02ouz3rz7D4biSJbmiabqyrbuC8fyTNf2jef6zvf+DwwKh8Si8YhMKpfMpvMJjUqn1Kr1is1qt9yu9wsOi8fksvmMTqvX7Lb7DY/L5/S6/Y7P6/f8vv8PGCg4SFhoeIiYqLjI2Oj4CBkpOUlZaXmJmam5ydnp+QkaKjpKWmp6ipqqusra6voKGys7S1tre4ubq7vL2+v7CxwsPExcbHyMnKy8zNzs/AwdLT1NXW19jZ2tvc3d7f0NHi4+Tl5ufo6err7O3u7+Dh8vP09fb3+Pn6+/z9/v/w8woMCBBAsaPIgwocKFDBs6fAgxosSJFCtavIhRVgEAOw");
}
```