# Change the color of selected option in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML <select> selected option background-color CSS style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402146/html-select-selected-option-background-color-css-style)

How can I change the color of the selected option in dropdown list? I need to change the color of the option which is visible when the dropdown is closed...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402146/html-select-selected-option-background-color-css-style

Answer (score 3):

You can get the value from `select.options[select.selectedIndex]`, so this might fit your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/6VhK8/.

```
var select = document.getElementById('select');
select.onchange = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
        if(i == select.selectedIndex) {
            select.options[i]
            .style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        } else {
            select.options[i]
            .style.backgroundColor = '';
        }
    }
}
```