# Change option background color on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

How can I change the background color when user hovers it ? I have tried this but it's not working.

```
<select>
<option>bmw</option>
<option>audi</option>
<option>mercedes</option>
</select>



$('option').hover(function(){
$(this).css("background-color","#FFFFCC");
});
```

Comment: Even if it could be done, you'd want to do this with CSS, not JavaScript.

Comment: i think this may solve your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402146/html-select-selected-option-background-color-css-style

Comment: take a look at this article : [jQuery Select CSS Style](http://www.1stwebmagazine.com/jquery-select-css-style)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Select List Option background colour on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use option in this way. The best solution would be styling something similar with `<ul>` and `<li>` and interacting with JS.

Answer (score 0):

`hover` event can not be bound to an `option` tag.  I'll update this post if I find the documentation or proof that says so.  In my experience, this cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already use jQuery, there is a pretty nice plugin - [image-dropdown](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) + [demo from the makers](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/index.html).