# How to change color of Select box after option is selected

Tags: css

I have tried a lot but can not do this. I want to show the red background colour to the selectbox after option is selected.

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<style type="text/css">
select:hover { 
    background:#Ff0000; 
    color : #ffffff;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Technically select box is always selected so you cannot tell difference.

Comment: does `select:hover` change the color if you are hovering over the drop down list? if so, i would try `select:visited` (like it is used with hyperlinks)

Comment: you want to this http://jsfiddle.net/j96Wf/

Comment: i have done the same Rohit i want red color after 1 or 2 or 3 is selected

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Select List Option background colour on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');
select.onchange = function () {
    select.className = 'redText';
}
```

```css
.redText {
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @HashirAzad this can be improve by calling the function in HTML. like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/LgD7w/1/).

Comment: The suggestion of  Mr_Green - divami.com actually works and is CSS only whilst the options below don't work (using html5, Mac Safari and/or Chrome) - highly reccomended!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript/jquery to handle change selection event for selectbox and add red background

Comment: can i do this with css with :after

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option selected>im selected</option>
    <option>im not</option>
    <option>me too</option>
    <option>me either</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
select { color: black; background: red; }
option:not(:checked) { background: white; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kQ6c5/

**EDIT**

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked:

> the `:checked` pseudo-class initially applies to such elements that have the HTML4 `selected` and `checked` attributes

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely yes, you can do this using `:checked` selector,

Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k46UY/)**</kbd>

#### Syntax

```
option:checked { }
```

#### HTML

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

#### CSS

```
option:checked { 
    background:#Ff0000; 
    color : #ffffff;
}
```