# How to change select box option's background color on focus?

Tags: html, css

When you select an option, the option's background turns blue until you click somewhere else.. I've tried to set the background color for focus and selected, but that didn't work. The background of options should be greyish at all times.

How to remove the blue background on focus?

http://jsfiddle.net/8LURy/

```
<style>
#row_demo {
    width: 15%;
    height: auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#column
{
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden
}
select
{
    padding: 1px 3px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.83);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border:1px solid rgba(150, 141, 124, 1);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 0;
    color: #D4C7AB;
    font-family: ABeeZee;
    text-align: center;
}
select:focus
{
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(246, 206, 120, 1);

}
select::-webkit-scrollbar {display:none;}
select::-moz-scrollbar {display:none;}
select::-o-scrollbar {display:none;}
select::-google-ms-scrollbar {display:none;}
select::-khtml-scrollbar {display:none;}
</style>

<div id="column">
    <div id="row_demo">
        <select id="culture" name="culture" width="277" style="width: 100%;" size="9">
            <option value='0' disabled style="text-align:center;">Select location</option>
            <option value='1' selected>North</option>
            <option value='2'>North-East</option>
            <option value='3'>East</option>
            <option value='4'>East-South</option>
            <option value='5'>South</option>
            <option value='6'>South-West</option>
            <option value='7'>West</option>
            <option value='8'>West-North</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried select2 and selectboxit, but it looks like they don't support a "block" kind selection box (without dropdown/sidebar).

Comment: That blue background is literally the browser highlighting the box,as it should... if you click outside of the box then it resumes the normal color. I don't believe there is a way around this.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091015/change-select-highlight-color