# Change <select> <option> highlight color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overriding

I have this:

```
<select name="idx" id="search-field_0">
    <option value="kw">Keyword</option>
    <option value="su,wrdl">Subject</option>                                        
    <option value="ti">Title</option>        
    <option value="au,wrdl">Author</option>                                                                    
    <option value="pb,wrdl">Publisher</option>
    <option value="pl,wrdl">Publisher location</option>
    <option value="nb">ISBN</option>                                        
    <option value="bc">Barcode</option>
</select>
```

[image]

I want to change its highlight background to green. How will I do this , without converting my 
 tag to any form.Any idea?

Comment: You can see some useful content here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388011/how-to-change-colour-of-blue-highlight-on-select-box-dropdown

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing <select> highlight color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667086/changing-select-highlight-color)

Comment: take a look at this article : [jQuery Select CSS Style](http://www.1stwebmagazine.com/jquery-select-css-style)

Comment: Is there have any solution for this question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can really change this with pure css.  this is browser / operating system defined colors.  You can do something a little hackier and make a custom dropdown using divs.  or maybe you can find some javascript library to handle this..

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is something for the *option highlight* you're specifically asking for.

Turns out there are multiple questions like this all over SO, although here is a good explanation by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091015/change-select-highlight-color):

> Well you cannot change the hover color of select option as it is rendered by Operating System instead of HTML

Comment: "*highlight background to green*" the questioner asked nothing of the background color

Comment: Okay - And I amended my answer to something that's worded right. I gave an option for a more customized style, and then some additional information saying you *can't* infact do what is specifically asked.

Comment: @Brian I apologise for you having a bad day - However I provided context AND code snippets. Please go be mean somewhere else?

Comment: Im sorry you're taking it as me having a bad day. Nothing personal, it's just not helpful to have the only valid aspect of your answer be a link to another question.

Comment: I realise I could of only said "Well you cannot change the hover color of select option as it is rendered by Operating System instead of HTML" - However I decided to link back to the original question for historical context, AND add an additional bit of information for some customization based on an assumption of what OP asked. I don't see how " a link to another question" could be the only valid thing.