# Html 5 Select List Option change background color on hover in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, select, onhover

Tried a lot to change the background color of select option on hover but unable to do so please help me to find the solution.

```
select.rangs option:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px #ffea00 inset;}
option.rang:hover {
 background: #ffea00 !important;}

<select id="order" name="order" title="order" class="form-control form-login__input-field label-error rangs">
 <option class="rang" value="">Sort By</option>
 <option class="rang" value="popular">Most popular</option>
 <option class="rang" value="register_desc">Oldest First</option>
 <option class="rang" value="register_asc">Newest First</option>
```

> I want the background color to be changed on hover in chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change select options hover background color using only css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574430/how-to-change-select-options-hover-background-color-using-only-css)

Comment: Also dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Select List Option background colour on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the `background` of the `<option>`, you can't set script or style inside `option` element. This is used to show only text inside option element no matter what text , style or scripts

The main property of option element is `value` that's why there is no need to add CSS on text inside `<option>`

You could only apply CSS on `<select>`:

```
select {
background: #ffea00;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Following code will help you. Run Code Snippet.

[image]

```css
.rang:hover { background: #ffea00 !important;}
```

```html
<select id="order" name="order" title="order" class="form-control form-login__input-field label-error rangs">
 <option class="rang" value="">Sort By</option>
 <option class="rang" value="popular">Most popular</option>
 <option class="rang" value="register_desc">Oldest First</option>
 <option class="rang" value="register_asc">Newest First</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Hi @wazz , He wants to change the background color of option on hover event And this working in my code. Is any problem? Please explain.

Comment: Doesn't work in chrome, or the snippet. How can you say it works?

Comment: Hi @wazz , its working on my chrome browser, Just a minute, I am attaching the screenshot.   :)

Comment: Hi @wazz, please check, if anything wrong in my output, then please tell me.   :)

Comment: The hover is blue in your image. The CSS is yellow.

Comment: Hi @wazz , You are right.. :)    I just put the #ffea00 in my CSS and not checked that whether it is blue or yellow.  Your reply helps me to find out my mistake, thanks for the reply.   :)  And, Sorry for the mistake. :(   . I will try to makes this output correct.

Comment: Check the original post's comments and links to previous answers. It looks like this is not possible. You can delete this answer too, if you are allowed (not sure how many points you need).