# select -option for colors and hover behavior

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

trying to make a selec-tor where the user can chose a color so ofc I just changed background color for every -option- the problem is that when I hover it the background is changed to blue which I don't want to happen -look the pictures for clearification [image]

[image]

I googled a bit and what I understand is that it's not possible to overide that behavior with css 
that code didn not work for me :

```
select.decorated option:hover {
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px #1882A8 inset;
```

}

-how can I solve that problem  - I'm using angular 5 with bootstrap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Select List Option background colour on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover)

Comment: I tryed the answer there and it doesn't work - so I'm guessing it's outdated

Comment: well, you have to build a dropdown that is the easiest way - so it won't be <select> but a <button> with dropdown <ul> list
Edit: or in the answer if you need to type as well you use <input> instead of <button>

Comment: which library are you using for custom dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way here is to rebuild a whole select with for example ul li, like this example:
https://codepen.io/marijoha/pen/zKjvEw

I just added inlinestyles for the

```
background-color:xxx;
```

as a example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MORwQd