# Add custom hover colours to <option> elements using and get rid of the blue outline CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a custom hover colour and border to the option element using CSS only but I can't figure out how.

**What I want it to look like:**

[image: What I want it to look like]

**What it looks like right now:**

[image: What it looks like right now]

**CSS:**

```
option:hover {

    background-color: white;
    color: black;   

}

option {

background-color: black;
color: white;
outline: none;
border-left: 1px solid black;
border-right: 1px solid black;
border: none;   

}

option:focus {

border: none;
border-width: 0;
border-left: 1px solid black;
border-right: 1px solid black;
outline: none:

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IMHO you shouldn't manipulate the browsers behaviour like that for design purposes. People are used to their browsers and may think, the page does not work or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option (no pun intended) which only works in Firefox:
[Change Select List Option background colour on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover)

There is no cross-browser solution for what you are trying to accomplish.