# way to modify the color option on hover

Tags: css

I have another problem when I refer to the option showing a blue color so that I can not edit the CSS option,has long searched and did not find a way to modify the color option on hover

```
/**
 * Option item
 */
option {
    cursor: pointer;
}
option:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
option:hover {
 background: red linear-gradient(0deg, red 0%, red 100%);
}
```

only work:

```
select:focus option:checked {
  background: red linear-gradient(0deg, red 0%, red 100%);
}
```

```
<select>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

Comment: Don't understand the problem. In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code -- including html -- in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There was no way to change the background color of the option on hover when it is indicated ,even i use the Metril Design mdb Is there a way to change that

Comment: Here is all the info you need [Change Select List Option background colour on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover)