# Vue-Bootstrap b-select option hover

Tags: css, vue.js, hover, bootstrap-vue, select-options

I'm using Vue-Bootstrap framework, I want to rewrite the css rule for tag 'option' when you hover the element

My code is like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3bvspfo2/13/)

```
option:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Why the background-color in 'option:hover' change the background when is not hover event, and not when is a hover event?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b-select` is a native `select` element once rendered.
The style of the select can usually be styled to a degree, however the options are usually very limited as they're styled by the OS and not HTML/CSS.

This is especially a thing on mobile browsers, where selects act very differently compared to a PC.

You can try taking a look at this question for some possible solutions, however they're very limited in browser support.
[Change Select List Option background colour on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover)