# how to set padding on bootstrap-vue select component

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

No way to customize option in bootstrap-vue select component.
I would like to add padding on top.
i try to modify class "custom-select" and tag option but i hanven't reached the solution.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `bootstrap-vue` doesn't offer a `select` form input solution that has a custom dropdown area, if the select is not **multiple**. More on this: [Non custom select](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select#non-custom-select)

This means that you need some workaround tools that do the job for you, like using a utility library. More information can be found on other Stackoverflow issues, like, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59066714/vue-bootstrap-b-select-option-hover). All of them say that the native select option can be styled only to a very limited degree - unfortunately, setting the padding is not included.