# How to change color of options under select tag on mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hi I have refered a lot of website but i dint found the solution that how can we change the option background color on hover as by default it is blue but I want to change the color to green. Please refer the screenshot below so it may give more clearity on what i m asking for.

[image]

I tried using this css code but its not having any effect :  option:hover{background:green;}

Comment: You cannot change the highlight colour of a standard `select` control. If you need that behaviour you would need to use a control which replaces the `select` with other HTML elements and controls them with Javascript, such as Select2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Select List Option background colour on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover)

Answer (score 0):

Select option form element designs can't be updated with CSS. If you are not using it inside a form, I would suggest you to use custom Dropdown with even listeners from javascript as -

```
<div class="dropdown-wrap" id="dropdown-wrap">
    <div class="dropdown-head pointerCursor" id="dropdown-head">
        <span class="sel-option" id="sel-option">DIsplay header</span>
    </div>

    <ul class="list-ul pointerCursor hide" id="list-ul">
        <li class="list-li" data-val="1">1</li>
        <li class="list-li" data-val="2">2</li>
        <li class="list-li" data-val="3">3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Add 2 event listener at least as -

```
document.getElementById('dropdown-head').addEventListener('click', (e) => this.showTeamsList(e));

document.getElementById('dropdown-wrap').addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => this.hideTeamsList(e));
```

Add event listener functions add and remove hide class from list-ul. For hide class you can simply use max-height property as -

```
.hide {
    max-height: 0 !important;
}
```

and overflow: hidden property in css property of list-ul.