# How do I change the background-color of hovered select options?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to change this blue color of hovered select options, or is it browser specific?
[image: select box]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Select List Option background colour on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover)

Comment: @bertdida Seems like it's extremely browser dependant and will never work correctly on all platfors, so I might just have to ignore it. Thanks for the help though, it does seem to work on Firefox indeed, but not on other browsers that I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use an external library for doing this. The native select is very hard to style, and get it working properly across all browsers. I have previously used [custom-select](https://github.com/custom-select/custom-select), and it has served me pretty well. Furthermore, there is a [plugin](http://plugins.upbootstrap.com/bootstrap-select/) for twitter-bootstrap that I haven't used myself, but may be what you're looking for.