# HTML <select> <option> How to set up click/selected color?

Tags: html, css, html-select, highlight

Hi there wonderful people. I have a question, it may be only related to firefox but, how do I change the color of the selected <option> when the focus is in and out of the <select>? I don't mean on :hover that works fine I'm talking when you click on a <option> and after that when you click out of the <select> object.

The intention is to change the background-color/color of the selected <option> when the <select> is in focus or not in focus. In Firefox it shows in windows system blue/white with dotted outline and in Chrome is showing in a lightb blue/white on focus and white/grey on out of focus... I don't want that.

CSS

```
.select_style{
   background-color: #555;
}
.select_style option{
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.select_style option:hover{
  background-color: #0f0;
}
```

HTML

```
<select class="select_style" size='3' multiple='multiple'>
  <option value="">Please choose</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You want to click on an `option` and give it a color, and when you click outside of this `select`, the color of the option should be preserved. So?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I Edited the post so it may be more clear now what I want to accomplish.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover You can try this.

Comment: @SatyabhamaReddy thank you. Most of the anwsers there didn't work but I found with experimentation one that did work derived from those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This made the trick, remember the code is using a a "selectbox" <select> with the attribute multiple it does't act as the normal "droplist" <select>.

CSS

```
option:checked{
    background: #00ff00 !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px #00ff00 inset;
}
```

Comment: but if anyone have a better solution fell free to correct mine