# Trying to change the option background color on hover in drop down select in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the background color on hover in select, I tried many ways and It wont change.Really appreciate If you can help,

```css
.selector {

  background-color: #252525;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #595E57;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
}

.selector option:hover{

  background-color: #1BA1E2 !important;
}
```

```html
<select name=""  class="selector">
             <option value="">Select</option>
             <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: What's the problem?  The options are coloured to `#1BA1E2` when hovered upon, which is what the CSS indicates.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Martin It should be in blue color cause #1BA1E2 is light blue color, It showing gray.

Comment: Oh really, but I see blue,  Please explain

Comment: @destr0id It's blue for me also.  What browser are you using?

Comment: @Martin Mozilla Firefox

Comment: @destr0id If I run the snippet above, it shows blue.  I'm on FF too.

Comment: @Martin Refresh the page I have put an image

Comment: @destr0id It's not showing like that for at least two of us.

Comment: @Martin You mean its not in gray color?

Comment: @Martin I have cleared the cache and tried on icognito tab too

Comment: See this for how it appears to me: https://imgur.com/a/oArolLY

Comment: May be that is a glitch of firefox, because I also used firefox and that giltched soo much that I switched to brave, try viewing from any other browser

Comment: @Martin Omg what is the problem :(

Comment: Possible duplicate [Change Select List Option background colour on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.selector {

  background-color: #252525;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #595E57;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.selector option{
padding:5px;
}
.selector option:hover{
  background-color: #1BA1E2 !important;
}
```

```html
<select onfocus='this.size=10;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();' name=""  class="selector">
             <option value="">Select1</option>
             <option value="">Select2</option>
             <option value="">Select3</option>
             <option value="">Select4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Form elements are rendered by the OS and not the browser, so the CSS isn't always (or even 'is rarely') applied. There are ways to change the highlight color in Firefox, by adding a `box-shadow` to the CSS for `option:hover`,  but this is browser-specific.

Try something like `box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #1BA1E2 inset;`

At the end it's not worth it. Think on mobile first. On iOS the options will be rendered in a very own way anyway. There are no colors.

Comment: Even this is not working :(, Problem with windows 11?