# change background color of option element in select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have a select dropdown, which has options element and div with emoji dynamically added to it.
It looks something like this

```
<select class="items-dropdown">
<option class="each-item">Lang1 <div>Emoji here</div></option>
<option class="each-item">Lang2<div>Emoji here</div></option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to change the background color of option element when hovered , tried `option:hover{background-color:}` and  also tried solutions in the [Change Select List Option background colour on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover)

Those solutions didn't work either. can someone suggest the workaround? should I switch to `ul` and `li` style on dropdown ?  I'm unable to style `<div>` also

Comment: I guess this answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/12836286/11352456

Comment: @RoseRiyadh this doesn't meet the "on hover" requirement though

Answer (score 0):

this comment is doing the hover section
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60073662/11352456

I think it's satisfy your requirement.