# changing default hover background color for option on react select

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, select, react-select

is there a way to change the default hover background color of light blue for options for react select https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select? Or is it also not possible for the reasons described in this other thread [Change Select List Option background colour on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover)

[image: react select options hover]

```
  const styles = {
    control: (base: {}, state: {}) => ({
      ...base,
      background: "#1b1d25"
    }),
    menu: (base: {}) => ({
      ...base,
      borderRadius: 0,
      marginTop: 0,
      background: "#1b1d25",
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: "red",
      },
    }),
    menuList: (base: {}) => ({
      ...base,
      padding: 0,
      backgroundColor: "#1b1d25",
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: "#1b1d25"
      },
    }),
  };


  <Select
          options={options}
          value={{ label: currentAnswer, value: currentAnswer }}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.value)}
          styles={styles}
          theme={(theme) => ({
            ...theme,
            borderRadius: 0,
            colors: {
              ...theme.colors,
            },
          })}
        />
```

Comment: they have provided the proper docs for it [here](https://react-select.com/home#custom-styles) or you can just use default html and css select for more flexible styling.

Answer (score 2):

in **React select** you can `style individual components with custom css using the styles prop`. to change the default hover background color of light blue for options  to another color you can achieve it like this  :

```
const customStyles = {
    option: (styles, { isFocused, isSelected }) => {
      return {
        ...styles,
        backgroundColor: isSelected ? "blue" : isFocused ? "green" : undefined
      };
    }
  };
```

this a sample example using [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-v2-custom-style-forked-9oml9u?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can include the `className` and `classNamePrefix` to the `react-select` like,

```
  <Select
    options={options}
    className="select-wrapper"
    classNamePrefix="select"
  />
```

-> Here `className` will include the class name for the select box .

-> `classNamePrefix` will add the name given as prefix to all the classNames under the select.

So you can add css like,

```
.select-wrapper .select__option:hover {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.select-wrapper .select__option--is-selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**Working Example:**

[image: Edit romantic-ishizaka-qh8css]