# Change the Background Color of a Bootstrap 4.6 Select Option When Selected or Hovered?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

Using Bootstrap 4.6, all my form select dropdowns have a blue background like this:

[image: bootstrap 4.6 select dropdown menu with options]

I have a `.scss` file setup similar to this:

```
// Custom Variables

@import '../../vendor/bootstrap-4.6.0/scss/functions';
@import '../../vendor/bootstrap-4.6.0/scss/variables';

// Bootstrap Overrides
$primary: #6b37c4;
$link-color: $primary;
$link-hover-color: darken($primary, 10%);
$WHAT-GOES-HERE-BG?: $primary; // <-- what goes here?
```

**My question:**

Is there a Bootstrap 4.6 variable I could change that would change this blue background color to something else, globally?

**If yes,** what is the variable name(s)? I tried `custom-select-bg` and `custom-select-background`, `form-select-bg`, and similar.

**If not,** is there a way to change this blue background for Bootstrap 4.6? I have no understanding of browser compatibility, but obviously would like something long-lasting. I tried several solutions on [html - Change select list option background color on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover/60073662) but many were out-of-date or hacky.

**Basic example**

I would expect the background color of a select option to turn yellow on hover, but it doesn't. I also **don't know how to prevent the select menu from closing** to inspect the CSS! Going a little bit crazy.

```css
#mySelectDiv {
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

option:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="my-3" id="mySelectDiv">
  <select class="custom-select" id="myCustomSelect">
    <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: No, you can't [reliably style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#styling_with_css) `<option>`s cross-browser/cross-os. Some hacks work in some browsers, on some OSes. But `<option>`s are *largely* OS-dependent. Use a [dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/dropdowns/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is not to style it. For real.

---

My second recommendation, if you don't take the first, would be to use a battle-tested select plugin, which already handles accessibility for you and has some decent options for styling the DOM elements. Under the hood, none of them use `<select>`, but generic (and style-able) DOM elements.

---

Making your own is not *that* hard, but far from ideal, because selects (or dropdowns) are some of the trickiest UI components. For example, the `.dropdown-menu` is expected to overflow containers with `overflow: hidden` in most cases, as nobody wants a sudden scrollbar on such a container when you open a dropdown inside it. That's where it gets ***really*** tricky.

For what it's worth, here's a *"custom"* solution:

```js
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(e => {
  $('.dropdown-item', e.target.closest('.dropdown')).removeClass('active');
  mySelect.value = e.target.innerText
  $(e.target).addClass('active')
  mySelect.focus()
})
```

```css
#mySelect {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  margin-right: -1.5rem;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}
#mySelect:focus {
  border-color: #6b37c4;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgb(107 35 196 / 25%);
}

.dropdown-toggle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 7%), 0 2px 2px 0 rgb(0 0 0 /5%), 0 3px 1px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 4%);
  border: 1px solid rgb(0 0 0 / 7%);
}
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:active,
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
  background-color: rgb(107 35 196 / 10%);
  color: black;
}
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
  background-color: #6b37c4;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="max-width: 200px">
  <div class="m-3 position-relative dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <input readonly value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Open this select menu" id="mySelect" />
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu w-100">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

It's meant as a proof of concept. Feel free to test it on all browsers/OS combinations and/or improve it, but don't count on me to update it for edge-cases.

If you do go the custom route here's a few to-do's:

- open/close using keyboard navigation
- add appropriate `role` and `aria` attributes to its elements
- make sure it renders decently on all mobile device types (ios, android). Use actual devices (or browserstack), not emulators. On emulators it will probably behave as expected.