# why css is not working on the options of selector in html?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I want my `options` in `hover` state to be yellow but it still blue and border rounding is also not working. Its working for the `select` but not for its `options`

this is my html code

```
 <div class="blackbar" id="blackbar">
<div class="title">
<span id="titleText">Screen</span>
 <input class="search" type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search Movie" >

 <select class="dropdown" id="fruit">
    <option  value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option  value="banana">Banana</option>
    <option  value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option  value="grape">Grape</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

this is my css code for this

```
#fruit {
    margin-left: 150px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 42px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    font-size: 24px;
    border: none;
     font-weight: lighter;
     box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
    padding-left: 50px; /* Add padding for indentation */
    overflow-y: auto; /* Enable vertical scrolling */
    max-height: 150px; /* Set maximum height for the dropdown */
  }
  
  /* Style the options */
  #fruit option {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 12px;
  }
  
  /* Style the hover state */
  #fruit option:hover {
    background-color: #cef106;
    color: #000;
  }
```

help me please

Comment: Removed `django` tag since there is nothing related to it in the question.

Comment: You will have a hard time styling a "buit-in" selector. Use a custom dropdown menu using JavaScript. Otherwise -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple responses over here: [How to style the option of an HTML select element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element) . Several of the offered answers work inconsistently, but the accepted answer is:

> There are only a few style attributes that can be applied to an
> `<option>` element.
>
> This is because this type of element is an example of a "replaced
> element". They are OS-dependent and are not part of the HTML/browser.
> It cannot be styled via CSS.
>
> There are replacement plug-ins/libraries that look like a  but
> are actually composed of regular HTML elements that CAN be styled.

Basically, currently you can't use a foolproof method to style existing `option` HTML elements "out of the box", and them work consistently across all browsers without creating a custom select/option solution or using something like bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/dropdowns/.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe do `display: none` on the select option and `#fruit > option` as your selector?