# CSS: Style the selected of select list

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a select list:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">Macrostructures</option>
<option value="2">Woven</option>
<option value="3">Mystic Bird</option>
</select>
```

Now when somepody selects an option the option has a blue background. I know want to change the background color.

I already tried:

```
select option:checked { background: #787878; }
```

But this doesn't work. How is the correct selector?

Regards

Comment: It is duplicate of below

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402146/html-select-selected-option-background-color-css-style

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
$('select').change(function() {
$('option').css('background', 'none');
$('option:selected').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
}).change();
```

Comment: ahem, you may want to point out that this is jQuery, given the user didn't tag the question with jQuery or javascript.

Comment: Is there really no css way?
Apart from that thank you for a solution.