# Select option background color doesn't change until focused on

Tags: jquery, css

Okay,

This is driving me nuts. I'm trying to change the background color of my SELECTED options in a multi select box.

I've tried w/ CSS and Jquery to change it, and it does work, but the background color only changes when you focus on the box. Somehow the SELECTED attribute overwrites the background color with #d4d4d4 gray.

Here is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/e6XLs/

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402146/html-select-selected-option-background-color-css-style

Comment: Extended discussions...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box

Comment: @JohnKurlak The question you linked does work, but that is the same problem i'm having, ONLY works on click. I can make it change color on click the problem is on page load.

Comment: And the answer is that it can't be done without writing your own custom control.