# Aligning the background image of a dropdown select option to right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add background images to the select options of a dropdown.

This is the code I am using:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

    .flag16
    {   
        height:16px;
        width:16px;
        background:url(http://imgur.com/l2KaB.png) no-repeat;
    }

    .flag16.us{background-position:0 -3664px;}
    .flag16.il{background-position:0 -1824px;}
    .flag16.in{background-position:0 -1856px;}
    .flag16.it{background-position:0 -1920px;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <select id="my_select" style="width: 180px;height:20px;">
    <option value="some Value 1" class="flag16 us">USA</option>
    <option value="some Value 2" class="flag16 il">Israel</option>
    <option value="some Value 3" class="flag16 in">India</option>
    <option value="some Value 4" class="flag16 it">Italy</option>
    </select>

</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/26Wgq/4/

How do I get all the images to align to the right?

Also, this snippet works only in Firefox. How to get it working in all browsers?

Comment: One option would be to start by Googling `background image dropdown`.  I'm sure there is plenty of information about this issue (especially compatibility - not all browsers support this), and good examples.

Comment: I don't think it will work like this in all browsers.. you can use a js plugin for stylizing the form elements

Comment: You cant set .flag16 { width: 16px } as you would want the option label to be wider than 16px

Answer (score 0):

Probably wont work with CSS for all Browsers. Also found this:
[HTML <select> selected option background-color CSS style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402146/html-select-selected-option-background-color-css-style)

but I will keep my eye on that, Used to do it via JS/Jquery only... maybe there is a better way.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be good if you try this one. I know this is not a solution but it can do what you want, just think about this:

```
<select id="my_select" style="width: 180px;height:20px;">
    <option value="some Value 1" class="flag16 us">USA<span class="as"><img src="usa.jpg" /></span></option>
    <option value="some Value 2" class="flag16 il">Israel<span class="as"><img src="Israel.jpg" /></span></option>
    <option value="some Value 3" class="flag16 in">India<span class="as"><img src="India.jpg" /></span></option>
    <option value="some Value 4" class="flag16 it">Italy<span class="as"><img src="Italy.jpg" /></span></option>
</select>
```

Now just create the css for the images and this is not that big thing :)