# multi select box selected background color

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I would like to change the color of selected item's background. 
I mean that blue color : http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/3200/c0b8e4b9ceac4122bc5668a.png

Comment: Duplicate of [How to apply background-color to a selected option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091866/how-to-apply-background-color-to-a-selected-option)

Answer (score 1):

Referencing **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2402154/1461021)** post,

> Currently CSS does not support this feature.
>   You can build your own or use a plug-in that emulates this behaviour using DIVs/CSS.

However you can achieve it doing Javascript which you can see **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2402266/1461021)**

```
var sel = document.getElementById('select_id');
sel.addEventListener('click', function(el){
    var options = this.children;
    for(var i=0; i < this.childElementCount; i++){
        options[i].style.color = 'white';
    }
    var selected = this.children[this.selectedIndex];
        selected.style.color = 'red';
    }, false);
```

Comment: there is not way for me to change the color of a selected option in a multiselect, neither its background color ( at least on chrome )