# Stylizing A <Select> Bar

Tags: css, select

So, I'm using a select bar in a site of mine.  I'm trying to change the background color of the options when hovered over.  Also, if anyone knows a good way to style the vertical slider, that'd be awesome.

Here's a fiddle of what I'm trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/zof9suLz/

```
<select class="scrollbar" name="mydropdown" onchange="document.location = this.value">
<option value="#">Search by State</option>
<option class="scrollbar-option" value="http://alabamaadoptivefamilies.com/">Alabama</option><br />
```

The odd thing is that when you go down the list using a scrollwheel, and land on an option, the correct color comes up until you move your mouse again.

I just need to change the background color when you hover over the options, but I can't get it to do what I want, haha.
My site url is: statesites.wpengine.com

Comment: Why do you use `br` inside a `select`?

Comment: I didn't actually create the select bar, my boss did, she's just asked me to style it.  I'm not sure why, I'll remove that.

Comment: If you remove all styles, you will see the same behavior. Therefore, it's the native behavior, not your fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe seems to me like perfectly valid behaviour, all the time I saw `select` in any webpage it behaved like that, i.e. background color on option being hovered over after scrolling only changes after moving the mouse. Just to verify I tried the [demo on w3 pages (try it yourself)](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) and added more options for scrollbar to appear - it results in the same behaviour, it is for sure not caused by conflicting styles.

As for customizing the scrollbar style, that appears to be a duplicate of this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser), quoting the most upvoted answer:

> Scrollbar CSS styles are an oddity invented by Microsoft developers.
>   They are not part of the W3C standard for CSS and therefore most
>   browsers just ignore them.

Comment: Alright, thank you.  Do you know if there's a style selecter that can change that light blue hover color to #1e1166, or am I just at the mercy of <select>'s limited capabilities?

Comment: @Laurens Montanaro, you can read more about that [in this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402146/html-select-selected-option-background-color-css-style), long story short, you cannot achieve different color using pure CSS.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Thanks for the help.