# How I can change the default blue color in select list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a select list.

It is having its default blue color which I want to overwrite.
I want to define custom color on `:hover`, *selection* and clicked(`:focus` and `:active`.).

I am using *bootstrap*. 
I've tried some code but it doesn't work.

I want to change that blue color into some green color for example. it should be same if select box is open highlight with that color.

Here's my [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7m2sY/29)

Here' the issue I have:

[image]

Please guide me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML <select> selected option background-color CSS style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402146/html-select-selected-option-background-color-css-style)

Comment: In `dropdown` customization I'll recommend to use [*Dropkick](https://github.com/Robdel12/DropKick), due to its easy use and as per your requirement customization.

Comment: Why this is not working ??

http://jsfiddle.net/7m2sY/37/

Answer (score 1):

Play with pseudoelements. You need to make a class .yourdrodown ul li:active, :focus and :hover and set the background color.

For example:

```
.yourdropdown ul li:active, .yourdropdown ul li:hover, .yourdropdown ul li:focus {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: select:hover, select:focus, select:focus, select.selected {
    border-color: #2AD2C9;
}   Can you please see the demo I added..

Comment: Maybe he needs to override some Bootstrap classes instead of making his own?

Comment: Use !important in the class that you want to override. Example: color: green !important;