# Tooltip z index is not working

Tags: css, html

I have a tooltip, I have given `z-index` for that element but its not working.

Background element color is coming.
I want to set the stack for that.

```
.tooltip {
  border-color: black;
}

.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

I tried to give position and z-index but it is not working. Please guide.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` will set the stacking of elements. You'll need `opacity`.

Set the `opacity` of the tooltip to `1`.

```
.tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you please answer this question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323678/how-to-overwrite-select-and-option-hover-and-color-in-a-select-list-using-bootst

I am struggling ....

Comment: @JavascriptCoder Can't change the color on `hover` http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/7m2sY/33/