# Change background color of clicked option in duallistbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Im using [bootstrap-duallistbox](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/)

Currently, when users click an option from either box, the option background turns blue for a second then the option is moved to the other select box.

[image]

I would like to change the color from blue to something else.

What state is this exactly? CSS applied to `option:active`, `option:hover`, `option:focus` do not work to select this state and change the color.

I thought this might work, but it also failed.

```
select:-internal-list-box option:checked {
    color: #333 !important;
    background-color: #FFC894 !important;
}
```

Nor did:

```
select:-internal-list-box option:selected  {
    color: #333 !important;
    background-color: #FFC894 !important;
}

select:-internal-list-box:focus  option:checked  {
    color: #333 !important;
    background-color: #FFC894 !important;
}

select:-internal-list-box:focus  option:selected  {
    color: #333 !important;
    background-color: #FFC894 !important;
}

select:-internal-list-box:focus option::selection  {
    color: #333 !important;
    background-color: #FFC894 !important;
}

.bootstrap-duallistbox-container:focus select option::selection {
    background: #ffb7b7 !important;
}
```

**How can I change the background color displayed when an option is clicked?**

#### Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgy8deb9/2/) showing the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change select box option background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color), or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402146/html-select-selected-option-background-color-css-style

Comment: @CBroe, nope - its easy enough to get rid of the default browser colorization with pseudo selectors - here is my attempt -> **http://jsfiddle.net/b4x3ar6q/**, _but what about the small delay when you click / move items_? That is the real good question :)

Comment: @davidkonrad Exactly! Turns out it's the `background` property, not `background-color`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out that to do this, you have to set the `background` property of the `option` not the `background-color` property like so:

```js
var demo1 = $('select').bootstrapDualListbox();
```

```css
select option:hover, 
select option:focus, 
select option:active, 
select option:checked
{
    background: linear-gradient(#FFC894,#FFC894);
    background-color: #FFC894 !important; /* for IE */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/bootstrap-duallistbox/master/src/bootstrap-duallistbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/bootstrap-duallistbox/master/src/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" size="10" name="" class="no_selection">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="option6" selected="selected">Option 6</option>
    <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
    <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
    <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
    <option value="option0">Option 10</option>
</select>
```

---

### Tested working in the following browsers:

#### Windows

- Chrome 45.0.2454.101+
- Fire Fox 36.0.4+
- IE 10+

#### Mac

- Chrome 45.0.2454.101+
- Fire Fox 40.0.3+
- Opera 30.0+

#### Ubuntu (thanks @davidkonrad)

- Chrome
- Fire Fox

**Safari** does see the property, it shows active in the inspector, but it somehow ignores it anyway.

---

#### My total guess at why this works

[Using CSS multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds) states:

> With CSS3, you can apply multiple backgrounds to elements. These are layered atop one another with the first background you provide on top and the last background listed in the back.

It seems to me that, the user agent blue background is still there, but the colored background added by `background: linear-gradient(#FFC894,#FFC894);` is layered on top of it.

Comment: Have you checked in different browsers and so on? It works here, both chrome and FF on ubuntu. So webkit and moz is OK.  It is really a good find. I would love to hear a CSS expert explain why it is so, but you really cant find any answer like this :) Perhaps because when you target only `background` - the overall completely generic - the browser accepts overruling all defaults? But again, really good. Remember to accept your own answer!!

Comment: @davidkonrad good call, I checked in all the browsers I have access to just now. `background-color: #FFC894 !important;` gets it done in IE but so far, safari stubbornly refuses to allow the change. Documentation on css related to the user agent stylesheets is really not available anywhere I can find but looking at some CSS specs, I updated above what I think might be happening. Ill be sure to close the question once the SO 2 day "accept your own answer" clock runs down lol

Answer (score 1):

For option contained in simple `select` I found  this solution (not working with Firefox 79.0 )

```
select:focus > option:checked {
  background: #red !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

But for option contained in select with '`multiple`' option - `<select class="selectpicker" multiple>`- I have to use box-shadow property:

```
option:checked {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px red inset;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

Additionally I was able to achieve control on `:hover` property in `multiple select`:

```
option:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px red inset;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to achieve the same behavior in simple `select` property.

**I tested it on:**

**Chrome 84.0.4147.135**

**Firefox 79.0**

**Microsoft Edge  85.0.564.44**

Comment: I’m not sure I understand, did you mean for this to be an answer, or are you asking a separate question?

Comment: This is an answer for question included in the topic, plus additional information about how can you change background color  of clicked option in `multiple select` element and hover event. If there is to many additional information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What I have tried in inspect element form [bootstrap-duallistbox](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/)

for options hover

```
.bootstrap-duallistbox-container select option:hover, 
.bootstrap-duallistbox-container select option:focus, 
.bootstrap-duallistbox-container select option:active  {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

Comment: I fail to see how this should be any different from `option:hover` etc, the same as OP mentions - it is the same and you still get the short default browser / OS colorization -> **http://jsfiddle.net/rgy8deb9/**