# change background of next div depending on selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

EDIT : It seems like I didn't make myself clear, sorry about that, so I update the code.

I have many "select", with different IDs and same class:

```
    <div class="objvalide">
    <select id="obj1-1" class="swit">
        <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <div class="switchy-container">
        <div class="switchy-bar">
            <div class="switchy-slider" draggable="true" style="left: 0px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="objvalide">
    <select id="obj1-2" class="swit">
        <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <div class="switchy-container">
        <div class="switchy-bar">
            <div class="switchy-slider" draggable="true" style="left: 0px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

... and more ...

Here's the JS I have so far:

```
 $(function() {
    $('.swit').switchy();
    $('.swit').change(function() {

            var select = $(this);
            var id = select.attr('id'); //alert(id); <- Works fine, I get the correct ID
        /* what do I hav to do here in order to have .switchy-bar bg change color only for this particular .objvalide > .switchy-container > .switchy-bar ? */
        });
    });
```

At the beginning, all options are "0".
Each and every .switchy-bar background is white.

When I select option value "1" in obj1-2 for instance, I need the background of its .switchy-bar to be red. If I select option value "2", background of its .switchy-bar has to be green.

The other select and background must remain untouched.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML <select> selected option background-color CSS style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402146/html-select-selected-option-background-color-css-style)

Comment: `$('.swit').change()` - will only fire when a select **changes** therefore `$(this)` is already the select. (You don't have to do `$(this).each(...)` since it'll only loop once) oh - and we need to see the HTML for `.switchy-bar` too to be able to help :)

Comment: Question: `if (select.val() == '0'){` you want to use this for selected? Because that's not for selected. You should `if (select.attr('selected') && select.attr('selected') === 'selected')){`

Comment: You are writing $(this).siblings('switchy-bar'). Please write Html for that where you are finding switchy-bar class.

Comment: backgroundColor changes using jQuery dynamically for switchy js. You need to make this bg color change after switch change complete.

Comment: @Sidney Liebrand: I deleted "$(this).each(function (){ }); and it does the same, so TY for cleaning the code.

Comment: @user3801953 every bit helps, it's all about understanding how things work either way - I just happen to know this :)

Comment: @Joshua Bakker: you're right, I tried to use the selected item with this part of the code. I used if (select.attr('selected') && select.attr('selected') === 'selected'){ }but still the same issue, all div are updated with the same color.

Comment: @Parth Trivedi : you say I "need to make this bg color change after switch change complete", but none of the pieces of code I've tried so far won't work :/ I can't figure out how I can achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.swit').on('change', function() {

  var myVal = $(this).val();

  switch (myVal){
    case '1': $(this).siblings().children('.switchy-bar').css('background', '#000');
    break
    case '2': $(this).siblings().children('.switchy-bar').css('background', '#f00');
    break
    default: $(this).siblings().children('.switchy-bar').css('background', '#fff'); 
  }

})
```

http://codepen.io/gmrash/pen/LpoGYG?editors=101

Comment: perfect! thank you so much, helped me really *a lot*. Now, I need to understand why siblings() didn't work earlier with my pieces of code :) I'll let you know if I find, folks

Answer (score 0):

```
select[0].style.backgroundColor=bgColor
```

If you want to change the background of selected option,

```
var a= select[0].selectedIndex;
select[0][a].style.backgroundColor=bgColor
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `click` event to fire a function that makes the necessary changes. Use the `this` selector to ensure your changes only happen on the element that triggered the function.

If you want to make the changes happen to the parent/child (parent in your case) element of the triggering element, you can always traverse the DOM relative to `this` using JQuery methods **`this.parent()`**/`this.children()`. For instance, if you want to change the background-color of a `<select>` element based on the clicked `<option>`, you can do that in the following way using JQuery:

`var backgroundcolor = ["red", "green", "white"];
$('option').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().css("background-color", backgroundcolor[$(this).val()]);
});`

Here, the array is created in order with the colors corresponding to each option.

Answer (score -2):

Please use **addClass("color-1")** and **removeClass("color-1")**. That is the only solution for this and do what do want in that class.

**Sol-1 (Without animate backgrou**nd)

In css

```
.color-1{
//Do stuff 
}
```

This will Help You.

Also

**Sol-2 (With animate background)**

```
 var record= $(this).find('switchy-bar');
    record.animate(
        {backgroundColor: '#FFF'}, 
        {duration: 'fast', complete: function() {
//Here You can animate with new color. and old animation will be overwritten
            record.css('backgroundColor', '');
        }}
    );
```

Comment: I disagree strongly with **That is the only solution for this** - there's nothing wrong with adding an inline `background-color` at all and removing it when you don't need it anymore. Tho this is a more **clean** solution.

Comment: This will not animate background as provided with JS. So inline changing don't make what animation needed.

Comment: I'm sorry to be an idiot here but *everything* jquery does like animating and such happens with **inline** styles so you're wrong. jQuery is just abstracting it away from you until you view an animating element in devtools

Comment: Changing color with jQuery and animating color with jQuery both are different things.

Comment: animating background color performs changing pixels Hex values with different time (fast,slow).

Comment: I'm not having this discussion with you as it's off-topic, have a good day!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95904/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-sidney-liebrand).